# как заставить selenium дождаться прогрузки элементов

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Использую selenium webdriver и c#. Нужно дождаться прогрузки странички, чтобы потом  запустить скрипт для парсинга. Перепробовал все способы из интернета, но браузер всё равно через 60 сек выдает ошибку timeout
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал варианты:

```
IWebDriver driver;
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://site.ru");
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
        var o =  wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.ClassName("class")));
```

ещё:

```
IWebDriver driver;
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait ww = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
    ww.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("class"))));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://site.ru");
```

и ещё:

```
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait= TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://site.ru");
```

Всё бесполезно, всё та же ошибка как на картинке

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` советовать не буду)

Answer (score 1):

```
[SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("loginfmt")).SendKeys("test@tgmail");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("idSIButton9")).Click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

`var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));`

```
var element = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("content-section")));
```